# error in xts - "'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'"

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to convert a csv data.frame into an xts and keep getting the following error:

the file is a csv daily stock data downloaded from Yahoo Finance for "AAPL"

Here is what I did so far:

```
library(xts)
AAPLcsv <- read.csv(file="~/Desktop/AAPL.csv")

class(AAPLcsv)
#[1] "data.frame"

AAPL <- as.xts(AAPLcsv[, -1], order.by = as.Date(AAPLcsv$Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

> Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, ...) : 
>     'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'Error in xts(x, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency, ...) : 
>     'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

Help??

Comment: Can you check the `as.Date(AAPLcsv$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`.  Please show few of 'Date' values

Comment: 2013-01-01 through 2018-12-31, all are in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` used is wrong in the OP's post.  It should be `%Y-%m-%d` which is the default format, so, the `format` argument is not really needed

```
library(xts)
xts(AAPLcsv[, -1], order.by = as.Date(AAPLcsv$Date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the format setting can help you solve the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).